# Inheriting from List<myType> or Extending List<myType>

Tags: c#, inheritance, extension-methods

If I'm creating a class, `MyWrapper`, to wrap a `List` of objects from myClass, should `MyWrapper` inherit from `List<T>`? Or `List<myClass>`?

Or should I just create some extension methods for `List<myClass>`?
I know it's against the guideliness to inherit from `List<T>`, but why?

Is there any drawback for inheriting from `List<Point>` or `List<T>`?

Is there any drawback for creating extension methods for `List<T>`? And what about creating extension methods for `List<myType>`?

And a example for a extension method valid for List would be

```
public static void Swap<T>(this List<T> list, int firstIndex, int secondIndex)
{...}
```

Comment: I would probably use a wrapper around List.  Your new class is not a List.

Comment: For sure there is a drawback to extension methods for List T. There is no method MoveTo(Point ...    I vote class that inherits

Comment: I'd prefer composition over inheritance in case you ever wanted to change the data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add extension methods to List, because you won't be able to code to the shape of all types of T.  What if it's a `List<People>`? What would "MoveTo" or "GetCenter" do in that case?

Yes, you should make a new class that inherits from List, or better yet, IList.

Or you could just model your "Point" class, then have a `List<Point>`, and if you wanted to add extension methods to `List<Point>` you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to derive List<>, the most evident drawback is that your user can't "guess" which method is overriden, and which ones is provided "as is". List is very rich class, especially when extended with LINQ, and a custom overriding of it can quickly be misleading and bug prone.

If you would like to provide List "as is", with a few custom methods, Extension Methods for List (where you target your specific kind of "T" !) could be really helpful and allow to preserve the original behavior of List.

Users will enable and use your Extension Methods only if they need them.
The drawbacks are the evident ones of Extension Methods : you can't do everything you want in them. There are plenty informations on web on Extension Methods.

IHMO the best thing to do is to encapsulate the List (or other enumerable) in your own class. Of course, T is specific to your own case.
The drawback is the need to redefine all relevant methods. Of course you can also expose the inner list (or, better, a Read only copy of it) with a specific property to allow user to directly use it. Your class can also implement IEnumerable.

Please also note that there are already tons of useful rewriting and extending methods and full custom collection implementation to improve List and other collections types on the web, and in Framework itself (most of collection types are misused, and LINQ adds a lot of good things). Take care to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: None of the members `List<T>` declared are `virtual`, so as a user of the type I *do* know which ones you've overridden - *none of them*.  You can shadow some of them, but you can't override *any*.  (You can override `ToString` and `GetHashCode`, as `object` defines them a `virtual` though.)

Comment: I don't remind well but I think you're right about this. So we could ask ourself "is it nice to override a class that I can only extend, especially if this class is so massive"

Comment: I fail to see how the size of the class is relevant here.

Comment: Hey Servy! Thank you for making my original post legible. I'm posting a comment because I don't know how to send private messages.